# Unable to click second link saved in List through selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to click all the product links one by one that are saved in a List in this [website][1]. The first product link is getting clicked however when I try to navigate back after clicking first link, The second link is not getting  clicked and giving error "Stalemate Reference exception". I am not able to get any other trick to fetch all links and click them one by one. Is there any other way I can do this as my links are getting renewed and driver is not able to find links after page refreshment. I am struck at line: elementToBeClicked.click();. Here is my code:

```
 WebElement prodList = util.getdriver().findElement(By.id("atg_store_prodList"));
                            // Finding all links and saving in a list
                            List<WebElement> alllinks = prodList.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='product-name']/a"));
                            System.out.println(alllinks);

                            for (int i = 0; i < alllinks.size(); i++) {
                                System.out.println(alllinks.get(i));
                                WebElement elementToBeClicked = alllinks.get(i);

                                Thread.sleep(25000);

                                elementToBeClicked.click();

                                Thread.sleep(10000);
                                util.clickbyXpath(Constants.BOOTSIZE);
                                Thread.sleep(10000);



                                    util.getdriver().findElement(By.id("atg_behavior_addItemToCart")).click();
                                    // util.getdriver().switchTo().alert().dismiss();
                                    if (util.getdriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Continue Shopping')]"))
                                            .isDisplayed()) {
                                        util.getdriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Continue Shopping')]"))
                                                .click();
                                        util.getdriver().navigate().back();
                                    }

                                    else {

                                        util.getdriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Checkout']")).click();
                                        Select selectCountry = new Select(

                            }
                        }


      [1]: https://www.barneys.com/category/women/shoes/boots/N-po186i
```

Comment: Nothing importatant, You can ignore that.

Comment: Please reduce your code down to an [mcve] so that we can get to the actual issue faster. You should also do some googling on what a stale element is and some methods to avoid it. By the time you've done this, you will probably find the solution to your problem.

Comment: Ok  I reduced the code as per your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

When you going back, all elements in the list become stale. To resolve it, you need to find all elements again at the beginning of the loop. please add the following code at the starting of the for loop as given below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < alllinks.size(); i++) {
    alllinks = prodList.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='product-name']/a"));// this will re identify all elements after going back.
   System.out.println(alllinks.get(i));
   WebElement elementToBeClicked = alllinks.get(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting stale element reference at `elementToBeClicked.click();` wrap this web element inside this code.

Code you can try :

```
 boolean result = false;
    int attempts = 0;
    while(attempts < 2) {
        try {
           elementToBeClicked.click(); // or web element that is causing stale ref.
            result = true;
            break;
        } catch(StaleElementException e) {
        }
        attempts++;
    }
```

**UPDATE:** Yes it is working at my end. try with this code :

```
driver.get("https://www.barneys.com/category/women/shoes/boots/N-po186i");
Thread.sleep(5000);

for(int i=0 ; i<100; i++) {
     int attempts = 0;

    while(attempts < 2) {
        try {
        List<WebElement> alllinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='product-name']/a"));
            alllinks.get(i).click();
            break;
        } 

        catch(StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        attempts++;
    }
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    // do your operation such as getting the detail of product or anything   
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.navigate().back();
    driver.navigate().refresh();
}
```

Comment: tried it, its not working. Did it worked at your end?

Comment: When it clicks on 2nd link, It is getting error---unknown error: Element <a href="/product/valentino-garavani-lovestud-leather-ankle-boots-505375259.html" class="name-link" precog_scanned="true">...</a> is not clickable at point (742, 5).

Comment: just maximize your windows. This is console output : The Row Fara Leather Combat Boots | Barneys New York
Christian Louboutin Telezip Leather Ankle Boots | Barneys New York
The Row Coco Leather Ankle Boots | Barneys New York
Sartore Chain-Embellished Leather Chelsea Boots | Barneys New York
Isabel Marant Dewina Suede Ankle Boots | Barneys New York
Maison Margiela Tabi Leather Ankle Boots | Barneys New York
Christian Louboutin So Full Kate Glitter Ankle Boots | Barneys New York
Christian Louboutin In Love Leather Ankle Boots | Barneys New York

Comment: I just ran the script for 8 items.

Comment: I don't understand by maximize your windows!, My window is running on full screen.

Comment: the error you are getting is just because of scroll down , your driver is not able to interact with the element because it is not visible to that. will you able to see the element getting clicked ?

Comment: No you should not , just run the piece of code that I have provided in chrome/FF browser latest. It works for me just fine. I have not done the scroll down still , it is working.